# LoadError: incompatible library version with nokogiri 1.6.8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I am working on quite old project which is running on old version of Ruby and Rails.

Ruby Version  = 1.9.3p551

Rails verison = 3.1.10

So when i am trying to configure this project on new machine the it shows
the error related to NOKOGIRI.

"LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/global/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
/home/global/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `require'
/home/global/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in`rescue in '
/home/global/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/glo/config/application.rb:7:in`'
/var/www/glo/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/2.3/nokogiri
/home/global/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:30:in`require'
/home/global/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/glo/config/application.rb:7:in`'
/var/www/glo/Rakefile:4:in `'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
global@del1-lhp-N01167:/var/www/glo$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
"

I have tried many things but still this problem is not solved.

So please help me out from this.

Thanks